# Cosmos DB - stopping IChangeFeedProcessor instance

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Change feed processor library to consume Cosmos DB change feed. The IChangeFeedProcessor creation code looks like this:

```
var builder = new ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder();
processor = await builder
  .WithHostName(hostName)
  .WithFeedCollection(feedCollectionInfo)
  .WithLeaseCollection(leaseCollectionInfo)
  .WithObserverFactory(observerFactory)
  .BuildAsync();
await processor.StartAsync();
```

In the ProcessChangesAsync() method of IChangeFeedObserver implementation, I call an external API for each document in the batch.

I would like stop the processor when the external API is down so that I don't read the documents from change feed when I can't process them.

How can I stop the processor(using StopAsync() method) when the IChangeFeedObserver.ProcessChangesAsync() implementation throws Exception?

Comment: Did you try making the processor static or part of a singleton and just calling it on exception from the `ProcessChangesAsync` method?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the actual issue, but if the problem is how to access processor inside observer, how about this. You can decorate the observer, pass CFP instance to the decorator, then catch/re-throw all exceptions, but in catch stop CFP.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the reply. I am not sure if I have understood the part: passing the CFP to the observer. If I can do that, my problem will be solved. Is there any example I can refer to, to understand how it can be done?

Comment: How about something like this:
`processor = await builder
  .WithHostName(hostName)
  .WithFeedCollection(feedCollectionInfo)
  .WithLeaseCollection(leaseCollectionInfo)
  .WithObserverFactory(observerFactory)
  .BuildAsync();

observerFactory.ChangeFeedProcessor = processor;
// The factory will create observers passing its ChangeFeedProcessor instance to each one.

await processor.BuildAsync();`

Comment: If you don't want the original observer know about CFP, you can decorate it with another one that would know about the CFP, original one will one process changes, the decorator will only stop CFP and do nothing with changes.